# Create a separate file containing rows sharing one specific column with same value!

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing

For instance, I have a data like below:

```
Transmit.123 Invite Members A
Transmit.123 Invite Members GC
Transmit.111 Invite Members F
Transmit.222 Invite Members DE
Transmit.222 Invite Members H
Transmit.333 Invite Members M
Transmit.333 Invite Members KL
```

Output should file should have below data:

```
Transmit.123 Invite Members AGC
Transmit.222 Invite Members DEH
Transmit.333 Invite Members MKL
```

Comment: What about Transmit.111? Why don't you want to see that one?

Comment: yeah I can do other way around also, where I keep unique rows and put duplicate rows (entirely, origin plus copy) in another file. Transmit.111 is also required but my big concern is to combine the values of column 4 of one which have duplicate columns.1 values.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
cat file |
  perl -ne '/(Transmit.\d+ Invite Members )(.*)/ and $a{$1}.=$2;
      END { print map { $_,$a{$_},"\n" } sort keys %a }'
```

Comment: no luck with above command!

Comment: @Shivani, what's wrong with it? It looks to me like it does what you need.